# No me deja retornar true o false

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer que retorne `true` o `false`, pero me tira error cuando creo la variable bool.

Como podría hacer?

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(){
    int z[50], n, i, suma=0;
    bool verd = true;
    bool fals = false;

    printf("Ingresar cantidad de digitos que desea sumar: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i=0;i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &z[i]);
        suma+=z[i];
    }
    if(suma % 11 == 0){
        printf("Es multiplo de 11.");
        return verd;
    }
    else{
        printf("No es multiplo de 11.");
        return fals;
    }

    printf("Total: %d", suma);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Eso es C o C++? Si es C, entonces, debes saber que C no tiene valores `bool` por defecto, debes hacer `#include <stdbool.h>` y cambiar los valores lógicos por sus respectivos en mayúsculas... Además, ¿Qué compilador usas?  Y, ¡Ah! `main()` no especifíca un tipo de retorno, por lo que creo que estás usando un estandar viejo del C...

Comment: Gracias! Uso Dev C++ 5.11

Comment: Si la respuesta que has marcado como buena te soluciona el problema entonces estás compilando en C, no en C++. Por ese motivo he modificado la etiqueta de la pregunta. Como te ha comentado @NaCl, el tipo `bool` junto con `true` y `false` viene por defecto en C++ sin necesidad de configurar nada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agrega la libreria stdbool.h

```
#include <stdbool.h>
```